# Посчитать суммы значений по разным месяцам и развернуть строки в столбцы

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

Итак, есть исходный DF:

```
YEAR        Sec X1
31.01.2000  A   5
31.01.2000  A   6
31.01.2000  B   7
31.01.2000  B   8
31.01.2000  C   9
31.03.2000  C   8
31.12.2000  A   5
31.12.2000  A   6
31.12.2000  B   8
31.12.2000  B   7
31.01.2001  A   5
31.01.2001  B   6
31.12.2001  A   6
31.12.2001  B   4
```

Необходимо сделать следующий манипуляции: для каждого из годов взять первый и последний месяца и посчитать в них сумму `X1` для каждого значения из `Sec`, а потом вывести их отношение

То есть на выходе нужно получить:

```
YEAR    Sec Jan Dec Otn
2000    A   11  11  1
2000    B   15  15  1
2000    C   9   NaN NaN
2001    A   5   6   1,2
2001    B   6   4   0,666666667
```

Comment: призывается @MaxU

Comment: Полностью согласен!

Comment: @Max52, а если встречаются другие месяцы (кроме января и декабря) - их игнорировать?

Comment: Да, игнорируйте! Нам нужно только отношение Декабря к Январю, чтобы рост за год найти

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте так:

```
mask = df['YEAR'].dt.month.isin([1, 12])

d = df[mask]

res = (d.assign(Year=d['YEAR'].dt.year, m=d['YEAR'].dt.strftime('%b'))
        .pivot_table(index=['Year','Sec'], columns='m', 
                     values='X1', aggfunc='sum')
        .reset_index()
        .eval("Otn = Dec / Jan"))
```

Результат:

```
In [17]: res
Out[17]:
m  Year Sec   Dec   Jan       Otn
0  2000   A  11.0  11.0  1.000000
1  2000   B  15.0  15.0  1.000000
2  2000   C   NaN   9.0       NaN
3  2001   A   6.0   5.0  1.200000
4  2001   B   4.0   6.0  0.666667
```

Для того чтобы понять как это работает проще всего выполнять команды пошагово:

```
In [18]: d.assign(Year=d['YEAR'].dt.year, m=d['YEAR'].dt.strftime('%b'))
Out[18]:
         YEAR Sec  X1  Year    m
0  2000-01-31   A   5  2000  Jan
1  2000-01-31   A   6  2000  Jan
2  2000-01-31   B   7  2000  Jan
3  2000-01-31   B   8  2000  Jan
4  2000-01-31   C   9  2000  Jan
6  2000-12-31   A   5  2000  Dec
7  2000-12-31   A   6  2000  Dec
8  2000-12-31   B   8  2000  Dec
9  2000-12-31   B   7  2000  Dec
10 2001-01-31   A   5  2001  Jan
11 2001-01-31   B   6  2001  Jan
12 2001-12-31   A   6  2001  Dec
13 2001-12-31   B   4  2001  Dec

In [19]: (d.assign(Year=d['YEAR'].dt.year, m=d['YEAR'].dt.strftime('%b'))
    ...:   .pivot_table(index=['Year','Sec'], columns='m',
    ...:                values='X1', aggfunc='sum'))
Out[19]:
m          Dec   Jan
Year Sec
2000 A    11.0  11.0
     B    15.0  15.0
     C     NaN   9.0
2001 A     6.0   5.0
     B     4.0   6.0
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 3):

Получилось добиться похожего результата так:

```
(df.query('YEAR.dt.month in [1, 12]')
   .assign(YEAR=df.YEAR.dt.year, Month=df.YEAR.dt.month_name())
   .groupby(['YEAR','Month', 'Sec'])['X1']
   .sum()
   .unstack('Month')
   .reset_index()
   .assign(Otn=lambda x: x.December/x.January)
   .rename(columns={'December': 'Dec', 'January': 'Jan'})
   .reindex(columns=['YEAR', 'Sec', 'Jan', 'Dec', 'Otn']))
```

---

```
Month   YEAR    Sec Jan      Dec    Otn
0       2000    A   11.0    11.0    1.000000
1       2000    B   15.0    15.0    1.000000
2       2000    C   9.0      NaN    NaN
3       2001    A   5.0      6.0    1.200000
4       2001    B   6.0      4.0    0.666667
```